# How to allow multiple work address for individual contacts

Tags: joomla

I would like to know if a contact person has the Work and Billing address already in his profile
how he can add a new Billing or Work or Home address again on CiviCRM.
at the moment it only allow to add 1 address type only.

Answer (score 0):

A contact can have multiple addresses of the same type ('location') - eg Work,Home.  That can be done via the contact summary tab.  If you are using a form or profile to update the records then the limitation is in how that is configured.

[image]

Comment: For email and phone it is possible, but physical address it only allows 1. So having multiple location types work (Work1, Work 2) is a simple solution.

Comment: If you have a Billing address already it would not allow to add. screenshot here https://prnt.sc/ohk_iQVVXvbq